# How to display data URI image in email generated by Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

How to display data URI image in email generated by Google App Script?

```
var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var subject = 'SP500 chart';

var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.barchart.com/chart.php?sym=%24SPX&style=technical&template=&p=MO&d=M&sd=&ed=&size=M&log=0&t=CANDLE&v=0&g=1&evnt=1&late=1&o1=&o2=&o3=&sh=100&indicators=&addindicator=&submitted=1&fpage=&txtDate=#jump').getContentText();
var tag_begin = page.indexOf('data:image');
var tag_end = page.indexOf('>', tag_begin);
var content = page.substring(tag_begin, tag_end);

MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, '', {'htmlBody': content});
```

Comment: Wrong tag - "appscript" clearly says it is for [APPLE MAC OS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/appscript/info).

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the Apps script compiler is not recognizing the string.indexOf() method.

Modified the code to retrieve the required value.

```
function testurl(){
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://www.barchart.com/chart.php?sym=%24SPX&style=technical&template=&p=MO&d=M&sd=&ed=&size=M&log=0&t=CANDLE&v=0&g=1&evnt=1&late=1&o1=&o2=&o3=&sh=100&indicators=&addindicator=&submitted=1&fpage=&txtDate=#jump').getContentText();
  var tag_begin = page.search('data:image');
  var searchString = page.substring(tag_begin);
  var tag_end = searchString.search('/>');
  var tag_endpage = tag_begin + tag_end;
  var content = page.substring(tag_begin, tag_endpage);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I added the following to your code and I tested your code. `code`  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 'test', '', {'htmlBody': content});`code` The image is not displayed in the email.